# java incompatible types: .io inputStream cannot be converted to java.lang.String

Tags: java

Tried importing about everything in the book and still coming up with this error:

**Error:(17, 34) java: incompatible types: java.io.InputStream cannot be converted to java.lang.String**

**also**

**Error:(24, 13) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Filereader
  location: class com.company.Bedford**

and for some reason it cannot resolve "filename" or "filereader"

```
package com.company;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;

/**
 * Created by brygu on 1/18/2017.
 */
public class Bedford {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // The name of the file to open.
    *fileName* = (System.in);

    // This will reference one line at a time
    String line = null;

    try {

        *Filereader* fileReader =
            new FileReader(*fileName*);

        //FileReader wrapped in BufferedReader
        BufferedReader bufferedReader =
                new BufferedReader(fileReader);


        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        // Always close files.
        bufferedReader.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(
            "Unable to open file '" +
            fileName + "'");

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(
                "Error reading file '"
                        + fileName + "'");
        // Or we could just do this:
        // ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: `fileName = (System.in);` what is `fileName`? Just drop the line and use `new FileReader(System.in)` a few lines later.

Comment: 2. error: You misspelled `FileReader` as `Filereader`.

Comment: `*Filereader*` are you sure that is your code?